# How to calculate the force required to move this pawl that swings on a pin?

Tags: design, forces

The structure (pawl) is rotating about a pin and is pushed forward by a spring. I want to calculate how much force it requires to push the pawl forward with the spring. Since the spring is only pushing forward, I don't have to account for gravity? Is it just the mass of the pawl multiplied by the friction it has with the pin? The pawl is around 5 lbs. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: if you don't have to account for gravity, then the pawl can simply float away from the spring

Comment: in the RH image, the centre of mass of the pawl is to the right of the pivot - and so creates a rotation force or 'moment' about the pivot - it is this which the spring must counteract.

Comment: would you be able to tell me how to calculate that force? is it just the vertical distance from the center of the pin to the center of mass multiplied by the mass of the object?